# Windows error sound(beep) in monodevelop

Tags: c#, monodevelop

I want do add that beep that windows play wenn there is error in my project in mono develop but cant find it. In visual studio is `SystemSounds.Beep.Play()`.

Comment: Not sure if there is a corollary... That seems like a very Windowsy thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it in a portable way so what you'll write will be Windows specific (by the way of course you can support more OS, if you need it).

Just import the [MessageBeep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680356%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function:

```
[DllImport("user32")]
static extern bool MessageBeep(uint uType);
```

You can get constants for `uType` from the above link, I suggest you put them in an enum and you create a public helper function like this (from [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.messagebeep)):

```
public static void Beep(BeepType type)
{ MessageBeep((uint)type); }
```

Where:

```
public enum beepType : uint
{
    SimpleBeep = 0xFFFFFFFF,
    OK = 0x00,
    Question = 0x20,
    Exclamation = 0x30,
    Asterisk = 0x40,
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

The `*.WAV` files are stored in the `C:\Windows\Media` directory. You could include it as a resource to your project.

```
SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.Error);
simpleSound.Play();
```

Comment: SystemSounds contains...sounds of the current Windows sound scheme, it's not to play an arbitrary WAV file.

Comment: @Adriano Yes on Windows, but he is using Mono Develop, which is cross-platform.

Comment: I need it yust for windows.

Comment: The name 'Properties' does not exist in the current

Comment: It's the path to the file. Can you install the WAV file to your programs directory instead of embedding it, then point it to that?

Comment: @DoroteaTomić if you're on Windows you do not need to embed (or deploy) a custom wave file to play it, you can simply call the Windows function (MessageBeep) that does it for you (in the same way a message box does).